# How do I set mount point and label for a LUKS encrypted ext. HDD?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, luks, device-name

Is there an "easy" way of changing the label/name/mount of a LUKS encrypted HDD, and at the same time have it mount at a Label name in `/media/user/` ?

Atm I have my disk listed twice in Dolhpin:

1. `3,6 TiB Encrypted Drive`
2. `3,6 TiB Hard Drive`)

and mounted under a name like

(`/media/user/`)`g976g98j-34f6-45hg-45g342346`

The disk is at

`sdb
   ---sdb1
        ---luks-da123qwe-123asd-123zxc-123qwerty
 /media/user/123qwe-123asd-123zxc-123qwerty`

TL;DR:

- LUKS encrypted HDD.
- Name it (e.g. `Label`)
- Have it mount at `/media/user/Label` instead of `/random-alpha-numeric`
- Have it show in Dolphin as `Label`
- A way not involving having to muck about with things that'll kill my system :/ Looking at you, fstab.

System: Kubuntu 17.10

---

PS:

By some stroke of luck, I have previously been able to get another drive to remember the label I put in during formatting (KDE Partition Manager). It mounts at `/media/user/Label` and is shown as such in Dolphin. Alas, I have no idea how I managed it. Lots or re-formatting, labeling, rebooting, etc. I suspect it's actually some sort of bug...

Answer (score 6):

Those random alphanumeric strings are UUIDs for your partitions.

In your case the partition gets mounted in 
`/media/user/string1`,
where `string1` is the UUID of the encrypted partition.

Then you have a decrypted partition, with UUID `string2`. You can see it mounted in `/dev/mapper/string2` when the partition is mounted and decrypted.

You need to give this latter partition a label.

**IF** your partition is ext2/3/4 you can label it via:

```
e2label /dev/mapper/string2 Label
```

Of course the encrypted partition must be mounted and decrypted, otherwise you don't see it in /dev/mapper.

(`e2label` is part of `e2fsprogs`, so you need to install it)